# How find a match for double value in cell in matlab?

Tags: matlab, find, double, cell

I have cell array with diffrent length that have double value.

> device_macs <1*44081 cell>
>
> device_macs{1,4} <2*1 double>

```
  1.412017896230000e+11
  6.196107856500000e+10
```

I want to find first match for a value , I try  `find()` but it is said`Undefined function 'find' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`
so what can I do??

Comment: Have you tried converting from your cell array to a numerical matrix? See `cell2num` and `cell2mat` for examples

Comment: I thing alternatively if you use curly brackets {} it will take the value in the cell instead of the cell.

Comment: I would suggest converting the data to an array. If the all cells contain a 2-by-1 vector of doubles, then this can easily be done by `arr = [device_macs{:}];`. You may of course also just use a for loop.